# How to get all data from datagridview into ms access using vb 10?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I am using vb 10 and ms access for database. I have a `DataGridView` which contains two column `("Address", "City")`. Every time I save two rows from each column to my database table. I always retrieve a total of 6 rows with 2 column each. The 1st and 2nd row of db are the same as the 1st row of dgview, the 3rd and 4th row of db are the same as the 2nd row of `dgview` while the 5th and 6th row of dbase are blank.

I don't know how to make my For statement right. I have researched so many links but I didn't find any close answer. Sorry for the inconvenience, hope you help me guys. THANKS!

my codes(under `cmdSave_Click`):

```
Sub DataGridViewDetails()
    Dim Address, City As String

    For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView.RowCount - 1

        Address = Me.DataGridView.Item(0, i).Value
        City = Me.DataGridView.Item(1, i).Value

        sql = "insert into Address(Address1 ,City) values('" & Address & "','" & City & "')"

        Dim comm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        comm.CommandText = sql
        comm.Connection = con2
        con2.Open()
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery()

        da.SelectCommand = comm
        dr = comm.ExecuteReader
        comm.Dispose()
        MsgBox("Address Details Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Add")
        con2.Close()

    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the purpose of these two lines of code? To me it looks like it is executing the same insert command again? (hence duplication)

```
da.SelectCommand = comm
dr = comm.ExecuteReader
```

As for the empty row, the DataGridView will have a empty row at the bottom to allow more data to be added, try change the for loop to this

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView.RowCount - 2
```

Comment: Amazing! thanks sir @mike bateman that works a lot. Now I can continue my project. God bless and thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes to the code:

```
Sub DataGridViewDetails()
    Dim Address, City As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView.RowCount - 2
        Address = Me.DataGridView.Item(0, i).Value
        City = Me.DataGridView.Item(1, i).Value

        sql = "insert into Address(Address1 ,City) values('" & Address & "','" & City & "')"

        Dim comm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        comm.CommandText = sql
        comm.Connection = con2
        con2.Open()
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery()

        da.SelectCommand = comm
        'dr = comm.ExecuteReader
        comm.Dispose()
        MsgBox("Address Details Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Add")
        con2.Close()

    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**First we must add the following declaration:**

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1  

    'Change "C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\Merchandise.accdb" to your database location
    Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\Merchandise.accdb"
    Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource
```

**Display button code**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MyConn = New OleDbConnection
        MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
        ds = New DataSet
        tables = ds.Tables
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [items]", MyConn) 'Change items to your database name
        da.Fill(ds, "items") 'Change items to your database name
        Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
        source1.DataSource = view
        DataGridView1.DataSource = view
End Sub
```